# Please check that the PPA name or format is correct

Tags: ubuntu, repository

In my Ubuntu 14.04 I'm trying to install the Captiva icon pack as listed on [this omgubuntu post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/09/4-gorgeous-linux-icon-themes-download). So I copy pasted the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:captiva/ppa
```

but I get the following result:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:captiva/ppa'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that your datetime is correct. I had an offset of two months into the past and got the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add this ppa and it's working. As a workaround to add it to your system execute the following under root (`sudo su` before executing the following code):

```
echo deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/captiva/ppa/ubuntu trusty main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/captiva-ppa-trusty.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B12AB791
apt-get update
apt-get install -y captiva-icon-theme
```