# Ubuntu : Check that PPA name or format is correct

Tags: ubuntu, ethereum

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to install ethereum blockchain as mentioned in the post below:
https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/installing_linux.html

While executing command "sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum", I am getting following exception:

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa/ethereum/ethereum'
Please Check that PPA name or format is correct.

I researched for this issue and people had suggested following solutions:

1. [Please check that the PPA name or format is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822498/please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct

I have tried updating the ca-certificates and have also checked my system's date/time.
Still I am not able to run the ppa command.

Any guidance will be of great help.

Regards
Anuj

Answer (score 1):

Is it taking some time for the command to return and are you by any chance behind a proxy (I've had this issue recently)?

If so, configure your proxy as described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/53146/how-do-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work-through-a-proxy .
Then, execute the command with **sudo -E add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum**. Notice the **-E** is important as it passes the environment variables. There are other options (env-keep) as explained in the link above.